# How to find the GameObject tagged as 'Player'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[[Picture]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1mE7.png)I am developing a game and am trying to make a save and load button. I believe that I have coded correctly, but my problem is that the player that I wish to access does not get found. I suspect that it has something to do with the way I am coding it.

Due to having multiple levels I have used the code:
    GameObject player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player"); to try and find the given player in the scene, but I do not think it is working.

I did not set the player as a public variable as it changes throughout each scene.

For example, I have attempted to access the players current health with the following lines of code, which is saved in a GameController empty game object in a script called Gamecontrol.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour {
    public static GameControl controller;
    int shooterHealth;
    int shooterScore;
//public GameObject player;
//public GameObject gun;
    int level;

// Use this for initialization
    void Awake() {
        GameObject player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
        shooterHealth = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().currentHealth;
        shooterScore = player.GetComponent<Gun>().score;
        level = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().level;


        if(controller == null) {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            controller = this;
        }
        else if(controller != this) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

    }
    public void SaveGame() {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath +     "/shooter.dat");

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData();
        data.shooterHealth = shooterHealth;
        data.shooterScore = shooterScore;
        data.level = level;
        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
    }

    public void LoadGame() {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/shooter.dat")) 
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath +     "/shooter.dat", FileMode.Open);
            PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);

            file.Close();


            GameObject player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
            player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().currentHealth = data.shooterHealth;
            player.GetComponent<Gun>().score = data.shooterScore;
            level = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().level;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(level);




        }
    }


}
[Serializable]
class PlayerData
{
    public int shooterHealth;
    public int shooterScore;
    public int level;
}
```

The error that I get is:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GameControl.Awake () (at Assets/GameControl.cs:20)

Does anybody know a way around this? Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Are you sure the player is tagged correctly?

Comment: Yes I am sure, I even tried changing the tags to different ones and it says the same error:(

Comment: Well that is strange. Can you share full script maybe you are doing something wrong in other parts of the code

Comment: Also is the player active in the scene? If not then you can not find it.

Comment: I have updated the code to show the whole script, and yes the player is always active

Comment: Can u show us a screen about your unity editor before pressing the play button(i would like to see the scene hierarchy)

Comment: I have updated a picture:)

Comment: Line 20 could be throwing a `NullReferenceException` either because `player` is null, or because the call to `GetComponent<PlayerHealth>()` returned null. Have you checked to make sure it's the former and not the latter?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `shooterScore = player.GetComponent<Gun>().score;`
You are trying to access the component `Gun`, but the Player GameObject doesn't have a `Gun` component attached. Maybe your forgot to attach it or you it has another name.

Maybe you attach the `Gun` component at runtime. In that case check the script execution order to verify that the `GameControl` script is executed after the script that attaches the `Gun` component at runtime.

Comment: I have just attached the Gun component to the Player now, but unfortunately have the same error, the GameControl script just can't seem to find the object with the player tag for some odd reason..

Comment: Have you checked the script execution order?

Comment: I checked the execution order and had added the Gun and PlayerHealth component to be executed before any other scripts, but this doesn't do anything either? Judging by the error I think it's the 'GameObject player =...' part.. if the player gets found these commands should execute

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object GameControl.Awake () (at Assets/GameControl.cs:20) -- this is the line where shooterHealth is

Comment: Maybe you have more GameObjects tagged with "Player". In that case you should use `FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")`. It returns a list of GameObjects instead of a single GameObject. You then loop the returned GameObjects and find which one has a PlayerHealth component attached and use it.